# SudzC iPhone Request

Tags: iphone, wcf, soap, wsdl

I wanted some clarification regarding SudzC for iPhone. Does SudzC support SOAP 1.2?
I tried using SudzC with the web service http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/CurrencyService.svc?wsdl and it works fine but with my web service it doesn't. The only difference I can spot is that the above service uses SOAP1.1 while mine used 1.2.

Regards,

EC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question. A service expecting a soap 1.2 message is not required to be backward compatible to soap 1.1 formatted messages. You can configure WCF to accept soap 1.1 messages [by creating a custom binding as show here.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/444434/java-Web-Services-SCDJWS/certification/WCF-Web-Service-SOAP) Although that WCF config is for a client, you can also configure a service to use that custom binding. If the service needs to support soap 1.2 messages, you can just leave your existing endpoint configured as-is and create a new endpoint for the soap 1.1 custom binding.